# Support same-resolution but different-DPI screens

Tags: android, screen

I need my app to support 480x800 **normal hdpi** and 480x800 **large mdpi** screens. The UI for them is **the same**. The matter is using `dp` in this case is a wrong way because on hdpi device everything becomes larger. But I need just scalable UI.
Is it possible I provide that by using single version of layout files?

Answer (score 0):

use 2 set of images and put in the 1.x mdpi and other in 1.5x hdpi

here 1 and 1.5 is size ratio

only one layout xml file is enough.

**EDIT:**
//while design keep in mind with 1x that is mdpi

//for example if you set 5dp for you mdpi resolution

it will automatically change for hdpi as

```
5*240/160=7.5 px  //for hdpi
5*320/160=10 px   //for xhdpi
```

Comment: ok, if I use `10dp` padding it is larger on hdpi... so, layout is not scalable

Comment: thanks but I need something like percentage. for example set width of element to 5% of screen width or like this.. to make the app looks equal on all the screens without writing many separate layout files